# Retrive ArrayList from SharedPrefernce

Tags: java, android

I have function for save and get arraylist in my application like below

```
public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<String> list, String key){

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        editor.putString(key, json);
        editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(String key){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = pref.getString(key, "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
```

I am trying to retrive it in my one of fragment like below

```
ArrayList<String> UserVideoLang;
```

and on create its like below

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
            customDialogBuilder = new CustomDialogBuilder(getActivity());
            parentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
            sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
            UserVideoLang= sessionManager.getArrayList("UserVideoLang");
            if(UserVideoLang.isEmpty()){
                UserVideoLang.add("all");
            }
        }
```

when I run I am getting NullPointerException on below line

```
if(UserVideoLang.isEmpty()){
```

and full error is like below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at com.vedagames.wowtok.view.home.ForUFragment.onActivityCreated
```

Let me know what I am missing and how I should fix it, Thanks!

Comment: plz share the method where you used saveArrayList()

Comment: @ShaluTD, I am saving it in settings activity, so its empty when I run first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharedpref is used to same small data for application. I don't know the size of the arraylist and single or multiple arraylist. If your data is large, you should choose Room Database for saving the data. You can check Room on [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) link.

OR,
For null check, first check

```
UserVideoLang != null
```

then check

```
UserVideoLang.isEmpty()
```

If there is problem with parsing Gson to Class object, you can use a easier technique for this. Like...

```
UserVideoLangContainer container = new Gson().fromJson(userInfo, UserVideoLangContainer.class);
```

Where UserVideoLangContainer.class is like

```
public class UserVideoLangContainer implements Serializable {
    public List<String> list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `getArrayList`  method with this

```
public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(String key){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = pref.getString(key, "[]");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
```

passing default value `[]` means empty JSON array. so if no value in shared preference empty array list will be returned.